# Splitting Paginated Blade

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade

Below is my controller code

```
            $category_ids = array();

        foreach($categories as $category){
            $category_ids[] = $category->id;
        }
        $paginated_products = Product::where('status',1)->whereIn('category_id',$category_ids)->latest()->paginate(30);
```

Below is my blade view code

```
$first_ten_products = array_slice($paginated_products,0,9);
```

But am getting the error below how can i fix it. Thanks

```
array_slice(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator given
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: I think you can run `toArray()` so it looks like this: `$first_ten_products = array_slice($paginated_products->toArray(),0,9);`

Comment: @andershagbard it brings this error Attempt to read property "id" on int

Comment: @NimaPatel i want to break down the already paginated data from the controller

Comment: you want to dived data into two part right? On which basis? do you want to slice it on based on count or on based on id?

Comment: @NimaPatel basing on their count such 30 as their length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is saying that `$paginated_products` is not an Array, and `array_slice` requires an Array to function. You can use `->toArray()` as suggested in the comments/your answer, but there are also Laravel Collection methods for this:

```
$paginatedProducts = Product::where('status', 1)
->whereIn('category_id', $categories->pluck('id'))
->latest()
->paginate(30);

$chunkedProducts = $paginatedProducts->getCollection()->chunk(10);
```

Some changes:

1. Use `->pluck('id')` instead of `foreach()`

The [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck) Method  returns a Collection of the speicified values, and is a short-hand for what your `foreach($models as $model) { $array[] = $model->id }` accomplishes.

2. Define `$chunkedProducts` from your Paginated `Product` Models

`->paginate(30)` returns an instance of a [`LengthAwarePaginator`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html), which has a method [`getCollection()`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html#method_getCollection), which can then be chained to the [`chunk()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-chunk) method. `chunk(10)` will return a Collection with X elements. In your case:

```
$firstTenProducts = $chunkedProducts[0];
$secondTenProducts = $chunkedProducts[1];
$thirdTenProducts = $chunkedProducts[2];
```

It would probably make more sense to pass these to the Frontend and loop them, like:

```
@foreach($chunkedProducts as $chunkOfTen)
  <!-- Do something with each group of 10 Products -->
@endforeach
```

But you can use the chunks however you see fit, and however works with your project.

Comment: This has also helped me write better code

Answer (score 0):

If I have refactored my code as below and it worked

```
                      $first_ten_products = array_slice($paginated_products->toArray(),0,9);
                  dd($first_ten_products['data']);
```

I just added the data property as above in the dd method and it worked